# Configure icefloor to prevent leaks when VPN connected

Tags: firewalls, vpn

I am trying to configure the icefloor firewall on OS X 10.9 so as to make sure all traffic will go through VPN.

I recently notified that even with "Route all traffic through VPN" option in tunnelblick some connections were made not using utun0 interface. As there is not this option in OpenVPN connect, which I prefer to use for speed reasons, I had to create custom PF rules that would block "non VPN" traffic.

What I've done could be summed up like this :

- Block all from 192.168.0.0/24 to any for TCP and UDP

Then I put some quick rules to allow connection to :

- VPN server
- OpenDNS
- Router

I notice that there are plenty of blocked connection to IP 239.255.255.250.1900 because of my custom rules and also 172.27.224.1.61176 > 172.27.XXX.XXX.47471 (my utun0 IP) blocked by the icefloor rule: block drop log inet all label "Generic_blocks_(IPv4)".

It all works most of the time but periodically [OpenVPN connect can't resolve DNS](https://superuser.com/questions/823181/my-router-bypass-the-dns-servers-i-manually-entered) and I am not sure of using the right settings here. 
I made some searches and 239.255.255.250.1900 connections are made because of UPnP but I don't know where I am using this. (no sharing or network printers)

Does anyone know how to properly configure icefloor for this?